# How to dynamically create buttons and track which is pressed?

Tags: java, button, dynamic

So I am trying to create buttons dynamically. But I don't know how they will be positioned, and where to put "add listener". I've looked at the questions here about creating buttons dynamically, but none of them showed me how to know which button was pressed. I've taken concepts from previous questions and integrated them into my code. Also, could somebody please show me how to change the button into a different image while it is being created in the loop?

```
Button btnArray[] = new Button[numMonstOwn];
    //ERROR HERE: the "layout" in "R.id.layout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        btnArray[i] = new Button(this); //initializing buttons

        //ERROR HERE about: "LayoutParams"
        btnArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        btnArray[i].setText("button" + i);
        btnArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        System.out.println("yo");
        layout.addView(btnArray[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `onClickListener(this)` in the button do `onClickListener(new MyListenerObject());`

Where `MyListenerObject` is created with the settings or whatever else you need to know what button it is for and what actions it needs to take.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. I ended up creating a class called "MyListenerObject" and will put the actions there when the button is pressed

Comment: No problem, accept the answer if you are happy with it. You should read up on "anonymous inner classes", they are very useful for things like button listeners.